# if i have Windows, Mac, and Linux, what is the easiest way to set up SVN server?

Tags: svn

i have Windows Vista, Mac 10.5, Linux Ubuntu... and wonder what is the easiest way to set up an SVN server?  some instruction to set it up seems quite complicated.  thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Windows server you should check out [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/). As their website states:

> VisualSVN Server is a package that contains everything you need to install, configure and manage Subversion server for your team on Windows platform. It includes Subversion, Apache and a management console.

Which I can confirm is true.

Comment: I totally agree. Easiest SVN server there is period! Performance aint too bad either.

Comment: I tried both visual SVN and the linux apache+svn. Visual svn is by far the easiest. Easy setup and nice tools to configure repositories, create users and set security.

Comment: +1 Indeed, VisualSVN is easier than my solution, hehe. If you want to have full control, then you may try mine